# Random, intermittant "unspecified" errors connecting to Access via ODBC in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2000

I have an old classic ASP web app that connects to MS access 2000 using ODBC.

I was able to get the site moved to IIS7 on windows 2008 and connected to the database.

When the app is launched, it works fine - but every now and then it gives an Unspecifed error from the ODBC provider on the page that was previously working. Hit refresh, and the error goes away... hit refresh again and the error comes back.

Anyone seen this type of problem?

One other note is that the old system had MS Access 2000, and the new server has MS Access 2010.

Comment: Bring us (to better the chances of helping you) the error message and the code that your using to connect to Access

Comment: I connect to MS ACCESS using a DSN system profile.  It is not like there is a problem with the odbc profile, since it will work and retrieve data.  What strange is that it would throw an exception running the same page if you hit refresh.